# Applying event handler on newly added element

Tags: jquery, events, dom

This is the the code i am trying in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#button1").bind("click", function(){
  $("tr:contains('Clothing')").after("<tr><td colspan='4' class='special'>Special offer!!!</td></tr>");  
  });

$("#removeit").live('click', function(){

  $(".special").remove();

  $("p").text("its remove");


  });

  $("#removeit").trigger("click");

});
```

Problem : when i click on `#removeit` button it doesn't remove the row(tr) with `special offer` I have added earlier, I tried different event method like: `live`, `on` but nothing works.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Adding event handler to newly created element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888570/adding-event-handler-to-newly-created-element). You will find very good solution there.

Comment: can you post your html part also?

Comment: it is something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/WJyBX/2/. also want to know if i add the "remove" button into html outside table rather then adding by jquery in individual row

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this (may be it'll give you an idea)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button1").on("click", function(){
        $("tr:contains('Clothing')")
        .after("<tr><td colspan='4' class='special'>Special offer!!!</td><td><button class='removeit btn btn-mini'>Remove</button></td></tr>");  
    });

    $('.myTable').on('click', '.removeit', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $("p#msg").text("it\'s removed");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WJyBX/1/).

Also [this could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648195/jquery-how-to-i-add-an-event-after-dynamic-create/12648263#12648263) .

Comment: I tried this but not workingnote : if i add .on it add the row rather then delete it)

Comment: this code is working in jsFiddle but not on mozilla, chrome etc.