# jQuery Plugins only work Initially

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery calendar and input mask plugins on my page, and they work fine. I have an Add button, which adds a row with textboxes but the plugins don't work on the newly added row. How can I fix this? If call the plugin code AGAIN inside the add button click event, they seem to work but I was wondering if there is a better way to make it work. Thanks.

```
$(".add-row").on("click", function () {
    // Add row   
    // Call AGAIN to make it work
    $(".time").mask("99:99");
    $(".date").datepicker();
});

$(".time").mask("99:99");

$(".date").datepicker();
```

Comment: Possible answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888570/adding-event-handler-to-newly-created-element

Comment: Yes, the delegated event is what he wants. I have a full example below.

Comment: My guess is that something is wrong in your add row code.  Can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the on() to an element that exists on the page so that the click event listeners are triggered from that element.

Try something like this:

```
$(".some-other-element").on("click", ".add-row", function(event){
    // Add row   
    // Call AGAIN to make it work
    $(".time").mask("99:99");
    $(".date").datepicker();
});
```

Change "some-other-element" to an element that exists on the page on init.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/bv27J/

Take a look at the API for "Delegated Events": http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). 

To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. 

If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.
```

Comment: Added a fiddle using a function call and a delegated event: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/bv27J/

Answer (score -1):

You have to call them again, but only on the elements you're creating. Something like:

```
$(".add-row").on("click", function () { 
    var scheduleDate = '<input type="text" name="txtScheduleDate" class="date" />'; 
    var row = $("<div><div class='div-table-col'>" + scheduleDate + "</div><div>").addClass("div-table-row"); 
    $(this).closest('h3').next('div').append(row); 

    row.find('input[name=txtScheduleDate]').datepicker();

    return false; 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Uat4R/

Comment: I have the classes 'time' and 'delete' inside the new row (textboxes) i'm creating but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you show me how you add the row and point me to the jQuery libraries you're using?

Comment: $(".add-row").on("click", function () {
            var scheduleDate = '<input type="text" name="txtScheduleDate" class="date" />';
            
            var row = $("<div><div class='div-table-col'>" + scheduleDate + "</div><div>").addClass("div-table-row");
           
            $(this).closest('h3').next('div').append(row);

            return false;
        });

Comment: @User970008 I said to call them again _only on the elements you're creating._ I'm using the exact same delegate method as you by the way.

Comment: I have textboxes on the page also which uses the calendar plugin so I have to call the datepicker code again outside the add-row event for it to work on other textboxes?

Comment: Every text box that you want to have the calendar plugin needs to be initialized, so yes. But if they are already initialized, you don't need do do it again.